# How can I recursively delete a set of directories across a large array of different folders using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have several config folders (ex: `.gnome`, `.mozilla`) that I need to delete across a large array of directories. They all start with two alphabetical characters (ex: `ag52156`,`ge51789`) and are located in the same place.

I don't write bash so I wouldn't know how to start tackling this in the first place - but what should I look into so that I can write this?

Comment: I think this would be the _proper_ answer: [man find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
find [a-z][a-z]* -type d \( -name .gnome -o -name .mozilla \) -exec rm -r {} \;
```